# Flowable Events are not in sequence (i.e. not in order)

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have `Flowable` subscription on a table, I get all data using following:

```
mySurveyViewModel.getAllMySurveys()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe({
                    showMySurveysList(it)
                }, {
                })
```

**MySurveyViewModel**

```
fun getAllMySurveys(): Flowable<List<MySurvey>> {
        return mySurveyRepository.getAllMySurveys()
    }
```

`showMySurveysList(it)` should be called every time `MySurvey` entity gets updated. I upload files to server one by one, on each successful upload, I update the counts in `MySurvey` which in turns `subscribe` method gets called.

I have observed that events are not emitting in order. e.g. If 9 files are uploaded, I update count to `9` but what happens, `subscribe` event for `9` count is received first and gives list of `MySurvey`s for count `9`, and event for count `8` is received afterwards which results in `wrong` counts displaying.

How can I make these emissions in order or How can I observe `Entity` for ordered events?

**EDIT: Audio uploads and Counts update logic**
**DAO**

```
@Query("UPDATE my_survey SET audiosUploadedCount = audiosUploadedCount+1 WHERE _id=:id")
    fun incrementUploadedAudios(id: String)
```

**Audio uploading and Counts updation**

```
for (audio in medias) {
    var file = File(audio.file_name)
    var mimeType = ""
    var parameter_name = ""
    if (step == step_audio_send) {
        mimeType = "audio/*"
        parameter_name = "audio_recording"
    }

    val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(parameter_name, file.name, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), file))
    var call: retrofit2.Call<JSONObject>? = null
    call = surveyApi.saveSurveyAudio("JWT " + AppPreferences.getString(user_id, "")!!,
            audio.submitted_survey_id, audio.q_id,
            audio.repeatable_id,
            audio.audio_marker, filePart)
    try {
        var response = call!!.execute()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
        mySurveyViewModel.incrementSurveyMediaCount(audio.submitted_survey_id)
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your logic for updating the count, and where and how that count is stored.

Comment: @SanlokLee: I have added audio uploading and counts updation logic

Comment: the code looks fine.. The order should be the same as in the `medias`